# Why am I getting 1 number short of my inputted number e.g 10 outputs 9

Tags: javascript

Building a countdown Timer with rounds, working and resting for training.

**Issue:** My timer seems to start fine (with the user inputted values) after the first round, once rest is done, my working timer doesn't start at the inputted value like it should. It's always one number short.

E.g If you input 5: 10: 10. When it comes back around, it will appear one number shorter than it should 4: 09: 00

From the left the Timer is rounds, working, rest.

Please help.

```js
let rnd = '00';
let wrk = 00; // this will act as my seconds
let rst = '00';
let prepare =3;
let interval;
let rstInterval; 
let startTimer = '00';
// store the working set in an array 

let prepIn = document.getElementById('prep');
prepIn.innerHTML = prepare;

// buttons
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', initTimer);
document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', pauseTimer);
document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', finishTimer);

let span= document.getElementById('app').getElementsByTagName('span');

function initTimer(){
    clearInterval(interval)
    let rounds = document.querySelector('.rounds').value;
    rnd = rounds;
    span[0].innerHTML = rnd
    let work = document.querySelector('.work').value;
    wrk = work;
    startTimer = work;
    span[1].innerHTML =wrk
    let rest = document.querySelector('.rest').value;
    rst = rest;
    span[2].innerHTML = rst
    console.log(startTimer)
    interval= setInterval(countDown, 1000);
}

// Pause the timer
function pauseTimer(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log("pauseTimer")
}

// reset timer
function finishTimer(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    span[0].innerHTML = '00'
    span[1].innerHTML = '00'
    span[2].innerHTML = '00'
    rnd = '00';
    wrk = '00';
    rst = '00';
    document.querySelector('.timeNum').style.display = "flex"
}

function countDown(){
    prepare--
    if(prepare < 10){
        prepIn.innerHTML = '0' + prepare;
    }
    if(prepare >=9){
        prepIn.innerHTML = prepare;
    }
    if(prepare <= 3){
        prepIn.style.color = 'green';
    }
    if(prepare < 1){
        clearInterval(interval)
        prepare = 00
        prepIn.style.display = 'none'  
        clearInterval(startTimer)
        startTimer= setInterval(timerActive, 1000);
        let work = document.querySelector('.work').value;
        wrk = work;
        console.log(wrk)
    }   
    document.querySelector('.timeNum').style.display = "none";
}

function timerActive(){
    wrk--
   if(wrk <=9){
       span[1].innerHTML = '0' + wrk;
   }
   if(wrk >=10){
        span[1].innerHTML = wrk;
   }
   if(wrk <= 0){
    clearInterval(startTimer)
    let rest = document.querySelector('.rest').value;
    rst = rest
       let rstInterval = setInterval(() => {
           rst--
           if(rst<=9){
            span[2].innerHTML = '0' + rst;
        }
        if(rst >=10){
             span[2].innerHTML = rst;
        }
            
           if(rst < 1){
               clearInterval(rstInterval)
               rstcount();
            }   
        },1000)

        rnd--
        if(rnd <10){
            span[0].innerHTML = '0'+ rnd; 
        }
        else{
            span[0].innerHTML = rnd; 
        }
   }
};

function rstcount(){
    clearInterval(rstInterval);
   countDown();

}
```

```html
<div class="timer">
    <div class="numb">
        <h2 id="prep"></h2>
        <h2 id="app"><span>00</span>:<span>00</span>:<span>00</span></h2>
        <h1 class="timeNum"><input type='number' min="00" max="99" class="rounds" value='00'>:<input type='number' min="00" max="99" class="work" value="00">:<input type='number' min="00" max="99" class="rest" value="00"></h1>
    <div class="buttons">
        <input type="button" id="start" value="Start">
        <input type="button" id="pause" value="Pause">
        <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you refactor this to separate the display part from the "timer" parts.  This has a feel of being too complex for what appears to be a fairly simple task.

Comment: Why is this done with script and not CSS?
 `document.querySelector('.timeNum').style.display = "flex"` possibly by adding/toggling or removing classes? (like an "active-timer" class or some such

Comment: Hey Mark,
I' relatively new, so structuring it may look all over the place. 
I put document.querySelector('.timeNum').style.display = "flex" there because when the finish timer function is called the user input values appear again, allowing the user to add new numbers